# Excel replace numbers with custom unequal ranges

Tags: excel

Suppose I have the following data

```
  Name    Output
   A        0.1
   B         7
   C         0.4
   D        0.9
   E        1.1
   F        12
   G        22
```

I would like replace the output variable by custom ranges:

```
  Name    Output   Output_2
   A        0.1       0m-0.3m
   B        7         6y-10y
   C        0.4       0.4m-0.6m
   D        0.9       0.7m-1y
   E        1.1        1y-5y
   F        12        11y-20y
   G        22        21y-40y
```

Right now, I am doing this (a long list of nested IFs)

```
=IF([@Tenor]<= 0.25, "0m-3m", IF([@Tenor]<=0.5, "4m-6m", IF([@Tenor] <= 1, "7m-1y",IF([@Tenor]<=5,"2y-5y",IF([@Tenor]<=10,"6y-10y",IF([@Tenor]<20,"11y-20y",IF([@Tenor]<40,"20y-40y")))))))
```

and it works but I am concerned that as the number of ranges increases, this will be painful to write. I was hoping I could write down a range somewhere and ask excel to look it up and do some case type thing.

Comment: Have you tried `VLOOKUP`? Seems like that would work fine.

Comment: @DougGlancy As far as I know, VLOOKUP can access records using a unique identifier and then read the different column values for a record. While "Name" is unique in my example, it is not unique in my actual data and even if it were, I haven't figured how I can use VLOOKUP to bin different "output" values into ranges. But I am thinking about it.

Comment: Yes, VLOOKUP is more suited to match data using unique identifiers. But you can use it for approximate identifiers as well. You specify this in the last argument of VLOOKUP function: 1 - approximate match, 0 - exact match.

Comment: oh I see. This is so cool. Thanks Taosique and Doug Glancy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume your first three columns are **A**, **B** and **C** (like in the second code block you posted). Add the following data into columns **E** and **F** (this will be your mapping data):

```
Output   Output2
0        0m-3m
0.25     4m-6m
0.5      7m-1Y
1        2y-5y
5        6y-10y
10       11y-20y
20       20y-40y
40       20y-40y
```

Then write the following formula into **C2** cell and drag it down:

```
=INDEX($F:$F,MATCH(B2,$E:$E,1))
```

**UPDATE:** you can do this even simpler with approximate VLOOKUP:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2,$E:$F,2,1)
```

Comment: Can I get "VLOOKUP approximate" to only approximate in one direction? For instance, I'd like 0.249 to be approximated to 0 and "0m-3m" rather than to 0.25 and to "4m-6m" ?

Comment: Yes, from what I saw the logic behind VLOOKUP matching is "equal or greater than". So if you have values 0 and 0.25 in your mapping data, 0.249 is mapped to 0 and 0.25 is mapped to 0.25.